# Exposing a reference of "this" from constructor

Tags: java, this, inner-classes

As per [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html) article, in the below example, it is suggested that a reference of "this" is implicitly escaped.

Now, an instance of non-static inner class can only constructed using the instance of outer class, now in below example, in the constructor of `EventListener2` a new instance of `EventListener` is created so how come the "this" is escaped implicitly. I know that inner classes hold implicit reference to outer class but point here is that as per article "this" is escaped implicitly and I am not able to understand how "this" is escaped, I would agree that an incompletly constructed `EventListener` is escaped but not able to agree for "this".

```
public class EventListener2 {
  public EventListener2(EventSource eventSource) {

    eventSource.registerListener(
      new EventListener() {
        public void onEvent(Event e) { 
          eventReceived(e);
        }
      });
  }

  public void eventReceived(Event e) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close to understanding.  It's not just that a non-static inner class cannot be instantiated without a reference to the enclosing class.  Instances of the non-static inner class actually **contain a reference** to the associated instance of the enclosing class.  So here, your anonymous `EventListener` contains a reference to the enclosing instance of `EventListener2`.

To understand why this is a problem, consider the (very likely) scenario that `EventListener2` has some other fields that are needed by `eventReceived(...)`.  Imagine that those other fields have not been initialized when you call `registerListener(...)`.  By registering the receiver, it becomes possible for `eventReceived(...)` to be called before your `EventListener2` is fully initialized.